# use react hook value in formik onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am creating a form using Formik. I have created my form following the pattern here:
https://formik.org/docs/examples/basic

Now I want to use the result of the useParams react hook (https://reach.tech/router/api/useParams) as an input to the onSubmit function.

This is the onSubmit part from the Formik docs:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
  }}
```

I tried adding this line:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
    const myValue = useParams()["myParam"]
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
  }}
```

where `useParams` is imported from 'react-router-dom'

But this gives me an error:
`React Hook "useParams" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

I am new to React/Formik and don't know how to proceed from here. How can I get the value of `myParam` inside the onSubmit function?

Comment: Where do you call `const myValue = useParams()["myParam"]`? Please show the full code snippet for this part. That would help in narrowing down your problem

Comment: I've updated my question to include the full code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentioned, you should call `useParams()` on the component level instead of in the callbacks (or non-components).

You can check the example in [this document](https://reach.tech/router/api/useParams) again

```
import { useParams } from "@reach/router"

// route: /user/:userName
const User = () => {
  const params = useParams(); //on the top of `User` component

  return <h1>{params.userName}</h1> //SHOULD NOT CALL `useParams` IN ANY CALLBACKS HERE
)
```

According to your code, the correct way should be

```
//I assume that `onSubmit` is in `Form` component
const Form = () => {
  const { myParam } = useParams() //you should call your `useParams` on the component level

  return <button onSubmit={async (values) => {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
    const myValue = myParam //replace for `useParams` 
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
  }}>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My confusion came from the way the form is structured at https://formik.org/docs/examples/basic. I adjusted it to match your structure.

Answer (score 0):

- React Hooks are particular functions that React uses to perform React logic, you can spot them in a React project since they are named with *use* prefix :
  ***useNameOfHook***
- React hooks can be invoked only inside the body of a React component, so they can't be nested inside another function as you are trying to do.
  (Check the ["Rules of hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to find out more about hooks in React").
- `useParams` is a React Router hook which returns you route params, so you just need to call it inside your React component, like this:

  ```
   // App.js
   const App = () => {
   const params = useParams()
   console.log("PARAMS", params)
   return (<div>{params.yourParam}</div>)
  }
  ```